# Powershell Script - list process with cpu, memory, disk usage

Tags: powershell

I want to filter my output. If I get the result of the following script. How I can result specifix process? - here my proprosal, but it doesent work:

```
Function Get-CPUProcess
{ 
$properties=@(
    @{Name="Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},
    @{Name="PID"; Expression = {$_.IDProcess}},
    @{Name="CPU (%)"; Expression = {$_.PercentProcessorTime}},
    @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.workingSetPrivate / 1mb),2)}}
    @{Name="Disk (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.IODataOperationsPersec / 1mb),2)}}
    @{Name="Path";Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.IDProcess).Path}}
)
$ProcessCPU = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Sort-Object "CPU (%)" -desc |
    Select-Object -First 5 |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
    $ProcessCPU
}
Get-CPUProcess -Filter {processname -like "firefox*"} | select * | Out-File C:\filename.txt
```

Comment: SO is not a free script (re-)writing service. Try modifying the script yourself, then post a question when you can't get something to work the way you expected.

Comment: With Get-Process, I see the complete path, for example: Get-Process -Name firefox | select path 

How I can get this information with  the class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process ?

Comment: You should be able to correlate the data by matching the `IDProcess` property to the `ProcessId` property of the `Get-Process` output.

Comment: In which step? - on the end of the script, where I call the function "Get-CPUProcess"?

Comment: You could use a calculated property with something like `Get-Process -Id $_.IDProces | ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach would look like:

```
$properties=@(
    @{Name="Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},
    @{Name="PID"; Expression = {$_.IDProcess}},
    @{Name="CPU (%)"; Expression = {$_.PercentProcessorTime}},
    @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.workingSetPrivate / 1mb),2)}}
    @{Name="Disk (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.IODataOperationsPersec / 1mb),2)}}
    @{Name="Path";Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.IDProcess).Path}}
)
$ProcessCPU = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Sort-Object "CPU (%)" -desc |
    Select-Object -First 5 |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
    $ProcessCPU
```

If performance is crucial, join Get-Process after selecting top 5 items:

```
$properties=@(
    @{Name="Name"; Expression = {$_.name}},
    @{Name="PID"; Expression = {$_.IDProcess}},
    @{Name="CPU (%)"; Expression = {$_.PercentProcessorTime}},
    @{Name="Memory (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.workingSetPrivate / 1mb),2)}}
    @{Name="Disk (MB)"; Expression = {[Math]::Round(($_.IODataOperationsPersec / 1mb),2)}}
)
$ProcessCPU = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Sort-Object "CPU (%)" -desc |
    Select-Object -First 5
$ProcessCPU | select *,@{Name="Path";Expression = {(Get-Process -Id $_.PID).Path}} | Format-Table
```

Comment: You mean:

Select-Object -First 5 | 
Get-Process -Id $_.IDProcess).Path

So?

Comment: Added another solution.

Comment: Thank you. After the function, Can I filter the export? such like this:

Get-CPUProcess -Filter {processname -like "firefox*"} | select *    | Out-File C:\filename.txt      ?

Comment: If you want to filter data you should omit `Format-Table` cmdlet.

Comment: Ok. I have tried Get-CPUProcess -Filter {processname -like "firefox*"} | select * | Out-File C:\filename.txt | ft   

but not works. Where is my fail?

Comment: See under my answer

Comment: There is still `Format-Table -AutoSize` in your script

Comment: Now I delete | ft - but why  Get-CPUProcess -Filter {processname -like "firefox*"} | select * | Out-File C:\filename.txt - not working?

Comment: You deleted `ft` but there is still `Format-Table -AutoSize` in function definition.

Comment: Now I get a output, but the Filter is not works. If I execute Get-CPUProcess i will become all results.